# Get Private Birthday from Facebook account

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

There are times that I can't pull birthday from facebook account, but only sometimes.

Could it be because birthday is set to private or can there be any other cause?

NOTE:

Sometimes it works properly, so I know I did right.

Comment: Can you ask a friend to set their birthday temporarily to private, and test? Or inspect the "failed" accounts: can you see the birthday through facebook's pages?